# Submit form but not add to history

Tags: php, html, forms

Now I want to submit a form, and process the submit with php:

First the current page is **from.html**, and then I follow to **here.html**:

```
<a href="here.html">Go There</a>
```

**here.html**:

```
<form action="somewhere.php" method="post">
    ...
</form>
```

In my php file **somewhere.php**:

```
<?php
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
?>
```

OK, now when I do this in the current page, I just go back to the `here.html`.

```
<script>history.go(-1);</script>
```

The problem is, I want the submission NOT add to history, just like I do `location.replace` to the **somewhere.php**. Can this be done?

Comment: Submit your form with AJAX and then use javascript function location.replace(): http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp

Comment: This will do the work, but more complex than before, I just want to make things simpler. @Phantom

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Prevent or clear back history with form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209590/prevent-or-clear-back-history-with-form-submission)

Answer (score 0):

Take a good look at the PRG method, that's probably what you need.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 0):

just submit form in onload event.

```
<body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
```